# Redirect to my domain page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

let me know how to redirect to main domain page in codeigniter. Like I want to Redirect my page to `www.example.com` from `www.example.com/folder/controller/`
Does anyone know?

Comment: u can use  redirect('/');

Answer (score 0):

First, get the url that the user is on

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; #www.example.com/folder/controller/
```

Second, you need to [parse the url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$parsedurl = parse_url($url);
```

Then, get the host.

```
$host = $parsedurl['host']; #www.example.com
```

Finally, redirect with `redirect`:

```
redirect($host);
```

*I didn't test this, and it's <s>pure php</s>, which I assume will work, since I don't know anything about codeignighter*

**Edit 1:** I changed header to redirect.

**Edit 2:** Forgot some semicolons ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use redirect.

```
redirect('', 'refresh');
```

Also change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in application/config/config.php

Add .htaccess to remove index.php .
Refer official [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)